# LowPower.idle isn't waiting

Tags: arduino-uno, power

I am trying to have my Arduino wait in a low power idle state given by the LowPower library made by rocketscream on an Uno. However, when I try to have it wait for 8 seconds, it seems to not pause at all. Does anyone know how to make it so it waits the full 8 seconds before running the next line of code?

Here is the code:

```
#include "LowPower.h"

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   delay(100);
   Serial.println("above");
   delay(100);

   LowPower.idle(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, TIMER2_OFF, TIMER1_OFF, TIMER0_ON, SPI_OFF, USART0_OFF, TWI_OFF);

   delay(100);
   Serial.println("below");
}
```

I would expect this to print "above", then wait 8 seconds, then print "below",  then do it again. But what happens is it runs right through the LowPower.idle without doing anything and the output looks like:

> 1:12:14.547 -> above
>
> 21:12:14.746 -> below
>
> 21:12:14.845 -> above
>
> 21:12:15.044 -> below
>
> 21:12:15.144 -> above
>
> 21:12:15.376 -> below

...and so on.

If anyone has any ideas on how to make idle wait, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting `cli();` before  `LowPower.idle(...)`. I think timer0 (used for millis and delay) is interrupting your idle time.

Comment: Thank you for your response but that does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this issue was brought up nearly 3 years ago, with no response from the author:  https://github.com/rocketscream/Low-Power/issues/36

Comment: That is unfortunate, but thank you for this information!